# When (and how) to lay out the children of a Win32 window in response to a resize?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, window-resize

Windows sends several messages when a window is resized:

- WM_GETMINMAXINFO
- WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE
- WM_EXITSIZEMOVE
- WM_NCCALCSIZE
- WM_SIZING
- WM_SIZE
- WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
- WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED

and possibly more.

If I would like to re-position the children when my window is resized, *where* and *how* should I do so?
I'm looking for the "best" method -- i.e. the method with the fewest gotcha's and the *least flicker*.

My *current* method is to perform all the repositioning inside `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, using `DeferWindowPos`.
However, I've also tried handling it inside `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`... but no matter where I handle it, it seems like there is *always* at least *one* "moment" when the window is painted in an in-between state, where the window's size has changed, but its contents have yet to be resized.

Another effect I would *also* like to avoid: moving a child *after* it has already moved. I don't want the user to see a control sliding down and then *back* up because of my change -- it should have as few transient effects as possible.

Am I doing this correctly? Is there a better place I can lay out the window's children?

Comment: Not much point in resizing a child window when only the parent's *position* changed.  WM_SIZE provides the least amount of flicker.

Comment: @HansPassant: Ah right, I wasn't doing that. `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` is actually a notification for the size, too. (Fixed a typo though.) Thanks for the info about `WM_SIZE`.

Answer (score 4):

You should re-position the window in the WM_SIZE message, because that is the last one that the window recieves before complete it's task...To re-position the window you can use MoveWindow